# C# XML serialization preserve list<T> order

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Currently I'm making a kind of History log using a List. I'm saving this list by simply serializing it with the XML serializer, however whenever I serialize the list and then deserialize it, the order is different to when I first created the list.

For example, when I first create the list, it may be in this order

1. A
2. B
3. C

Yet when I serialize/deserialize it may become something like

1. B
2. C
3. A

Is there a way or forcing the serializer to preserve the order of the list when serializing? (I've found it actually saves it in the wrong order to begin with)

Current Code:

```
public static List<StoredData> clipboardData = new List<StoredData>();

private void SaveClipboard()
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<StoredData>));

    using (StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(historyFile))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(stream, clipboardData);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Saved");
}
```

StoredData Class

```
[Serializable]
public class StoredData
{
    public String storedClip;
    public DateTime storedTime;
}
```

Comment: Which serializer are you using?

Comment: @Baldrick The XML serializer

Comment: I'm almost certain the XmlSerializer preserves order of Lists. Can you post the code and declaration for the List which is behaving this way?

Comment: @Baldrick I thought the same thing but for whatever reason it doesn't seem to be doing it. Updated the post with the code, see if that helps.

Comment: Can you post your XML? Something's fishy here. The order should be preserved.

Comment: Do you have a clear case where the ordering changes? Is the ordering incorrect in the file, or only when you deserialize from the file?

Comment: Ah, I didn't actually realise it was reversing the order of the list between being saved and loaded. I couldn't tell seeing as I wasn't working with data that was easily recognisable. It seems to have fixed it with a List.Reverse() put into the loading. Should I delete this question?

Comment: @user1363526: IIRC, it still shouldn't be reversing. I don't know if you want to delete the question or not, but from where I'm sitting, you should _not_ have to calls `Reverse` on it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way to preserve the order when serializing your XML

```
[Serializable]
public class StoredData
{
    [Datamember(Name = "Clip", Order = 1)]
    public String storedClip;
    [Datamember(Name = "Time", Order = 2)]
    public DateTime storedTime;
}
```

Comment: No, the problem is not the object being (de)serialized in the wrong order

Comment: Gets or sets the order of serialization and deserialization of a member.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.order(v=vs.110).aspx